# How to cancel infinitely repeatable Flowable on client disconnect?

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, reactive

```
Flowable.create<String>({
        it.onNext("test)
        it.onComplete()
    }
}, BackpressureStrategy.MISSING).doOnCancel {
    println("canceled")}.repeat()
```

This is the code from which I am trying to create a Flowable which emits something infinitely until client disconnects, in my case the client is POSTMAN. I am able to emit infinitely but the cancel block never executes on request cancellation

I would like the doCancel block to be executed

Comment: How can you tell when the client disconnected?

Comment: I'd say when emits don't get delivered or downstream signals a disconnect or cancel